# Aerospike client timeout error : timeout=0 iterations=3 failedNodes=3 failedConns=0

Tags: aerospike, aerospike-ce

I need to integrate the aerospike in my sprint boot application for caching purpose but i am getting the client timeout error.
Aerospike mvn dependency :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.aerospike</groupId>
            <artifactId>aerospike-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
```

Java version : 17
Sprint boot version : 2.5.12

```
@Service
class AerospikeClientFactoryImpl {

    private final ConcurrentMap<Triple<String, Integer, String>, STLAerospikeClient> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private final ConcurrentMap<Triple<String, String, String>, STLAerospikeClient> mapForClientCreationBasedOnCacheTypeStrategy = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    
    public synchronized STLAerospikeClient getOrCreateCacheClient(String namespace, String host, int port,
            int expireInSec) throws AerospikeException {
        Triple<String, Integer, String> entryKey = Triple.of(host, expireInSec, namespace);
        STLAerospikeClient STLAerospikeClient = map.get(Triple.of(host, expireInSec, namespace));
        if (STLAerospikeClient == null) {
            STLAerospikeClient = new STLAerospikeClient(namespace, host, port, expireInSec);
            map.put(entryKey, STLAerospikeClient);
        }
        return STLAerospikeClient;
    }

    public synchronized STLAerospikeClient getOrCreateCacheClient(String namespace, WritePolicy writePolicy,
            String host, int port, int expireInSec) throws AerospikeException {
        Triple<String, Integer, String> entryKey = Triple.of(host, expireInSec, namespace);
        STLAerospikeClient STLAerospikeClient = map.get(Triple.of(host, expireInSec, namespace));
        if (STLAerospikeClient == null) {
            STLAerospikeClient = new STLAerospikeClient(namespace, writePolicy, host, port, expireInSec);
            map.put(entryKey, STLAerospikeClient);
        }
        return STLAerospikeClient;
    }
}

@Service
@PropertySource({"classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"})
public class LockerImpl implements Locker {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LockerImpl.class);

    private String LOCKER_NAMESPACE;
    private static final int EXPIRE_IN_SEC = 30;
    private static final String LOCK = "lock";

    private final String host;

    private final Integer port;

    private STLAerospikeClient aerospikeClient; 
    
    @Autowired
    private AerospikeClientFactory aerospikeClientFactory;

    @Autowired
    public LockerImpl(@Value("${aerospike.hosts}") String host,@Value("${aerospike.port}") Integer port, @Value("${aerospike.namespace}") String cacheNameSpace, AerospikeClientFactory clientFactory) throws AerospikeException {
        this.host=host;
        this.port=port;
        this.LOCKER_NAMESPACE = cacheNameSpace;
        WritePolicy writePolicy = new WritePolicy();
        writePolicy.recordExistsAction = RecordExistsAction.CREATE_ONLY;
        aerospikeClient = clientFactory.getOrCreateCacheClient(LOCKER_NAMESPACE, writePolicy, host, port,
                EXPIRE_IN_SEC);
    }

    
    @Override
    public boolean acquireLock(LockerType lockerType, String key) {
        try {
            Key aKey = new Key(aerospikeClient.getNamespace(), lockerType.name(), key);
            String valueToWrite = ip + new Date().getTime();
            Bin bin = new Bin(LOCK, valueToWrite);
            try {
                aerospikeClient.getClient().put(aerospikeClient.getWritePolicy(), aKey, bin);
            } catch (AerospikeException ex) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception in taking lock locker type " + lockerType.name() + " on key " + key, ex);
                return false;
            }
            Record record = aerospikeClient.getClient().get(null, aKey);
            String valueReceived = (String) record.getValue(LOCK);
            return StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(valueToWrite, valueReceived);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception in taking lock locker type " + lockerType.name() + " on key " + key, ex);
            return false;
        }
    }

@Override
    public void releaseLockQuietly(LockerType lockerType, String key) {
        try {
            Key aKey = new Key(aerospikeClient.getNamespace(), lockerType.name(), key);
            boolean success;
            int retryLimit = 3;
            int count = 1;
            do {
                success = aerospikeClient.getClient().delete(aerospikeClient.getWritePolicy(), aKey);
                count++;
            } while (!success && count <= retryLimit);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception in releaseLockQuietly", ex);
        }
    }
```

Aerospike have default timeout of 1 sec.

Aerospike server are working fine, i have can see some connections on server but getting this timeout error very frequently.
There is not much traffic, TPS is less then 1.
Unable to findout the root cause.